# Spatial Analyst interactive tool bar histogram bins

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst

In ArcGIS 10.2, after I have created an histogram from the spatial analyst interactive tool bar, how do I collapse the number of bins to a smaller number?

Answer (score 1):

[Respective ArcGIS Help page](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005900000008000000) states that the histogram you see on your screen honours the extent of the raster (if you zoom in or out, the histogram output will change and you will see counts of the current extent) and symbology used defines the number of bins/categories that you will see on your histogram.

If you re-symbolise your data by using "Classified" (if you have single band integer/float raster, and by using "Exclusion..." facility in symbology, if needs be) or [Reclassify](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z000000sr000000.htm) your data by excluding unwanted categories (if you have nominal/ordinal raster), you would be able to control the number of categories to be shown.